# Are there good calibration results (OpenCV) for cameras with known parameters (matrix size and focal length for the lens)?

Tags: c#, opencv, camera-calibration, distortion

I did a lot of calibrations for my camera, but I couldn't get a good result.

I use a camera with a matrix of 1/3 "Live MOS. (4.54 * 3.42 mm)

Lens:
Format (inch): 1/3 ", 1/4"
Focal Length: 1.8mm
Aperture: F 2.0
Horizontal Field: 170 °
Operation Mode:
Iris Type: FIXED
Focus Type: FIXED
Zoom Type: FIXED

Could good calibration results be found for such parameters? There is a software for calculating the matrix by the known parameters?

Comment: Good calibration results need real images of a calibration pattern (e.g. chessboard pattern). With the information you mentioned, you can only guess the principal point (resolution.width / 2, resolution.height / 2) and the focal length in pixel: fx_in_px = fx_in_mm * resolution.width / sensor.width_in_mm For distortion parameters, you need real images.

Comment: @Catree, thanks for the reply! I want to find the matrix for the ideal situation (when the main point in the center). I think this may be more useful than my results.

If I understand correctly, then I can calculate the focal length in pixels, based on the physical dimensions of the matrix. Is it true?

Comment: Yes, you can calculate the focal length in pixel according to the real sensor size (in mm for example). In computer vision, we need the focal length in pixel since this is a basis unit. Have a look also at: http://answers.opencv.org/question/17076/conversion-focal-distance-from-mm-to-pixels/?answer=17180#post-id-17180

Comment: Thanks! I made functions for correction matrix parameters and coefficients in my program. I got a better results than the original (after calibration). This means that any calibration results can be improved manually.

Comment: How do you test for the accuracy of your intrinsic parameters?

Comment: I using test field with evenly distributed QR. The quality indicator is the number of recognized codes and its location (i want to reading codes in angles)

Comment: My main goal is to create a universal calibration for multiple cameras. By changing the parameters, I can make individual settings without calibrating each camera (they are physically inaccessible for calibration)

I think i solved this problem. Thank you for your help!